# how to cache Google API key string to memory?

Tags: android, google-api

I'm developing an Android app that uses Google Places API.

In order to keep the Google API Key out of the application code, I fetch it from my own authenticated API server and its needed in many places around the app.

what is the best way of storing / caching it to memory ?

I understand that just using a singleton will be garbage collected.
is extending the `Application` class and adding methods to there a good method ?
anything else I might consider ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

To save to preferences:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("MYAPIKEY",
      "myStringToSave").commit();
```

To get a stored preference:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("MYAPIKEY",
     "defaultStringIfNothingFound");
```

Where context is your Context.

Once you get it from server, save it. You can then access it as and when you want. Uninstalling an app will of course remove its contents. Else it is persistant.

Comment: this is not a secure way to handle the API key. I want to fetch it from my server whenever needed and keep it as a String in memory for later uses.

Comment: @GalBen-Haim I dont think you quite followed my answer. You fetch the API Key from your server securely, then store it like so. It can only be accessed by your app. For added peace of mind you can even use a custom encript/decript before storing in preference manager. It is just a way to create a secure, persistant stored string which is what you asked for. This will not be garbage collected..

Comment: but still anyone can get the key if its persistent stored, what I'm thinking is to keep it in memory only and fetch it whenever its needed and not in memory.

Comment: @GalBen-Haim If the user is determined, they can get at anything. SharedPrefs by default are not world readable and can only be read using the apps UID. Either use the singleton and regrab every time its been GCed, or store in sharedPrefs, and encript/decript for added security. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/adding-a-measure-of-security-to-androids-shared-preferences/109

Answer (score 0):

A VM cannot garbage collect string references that classes can still reach, so I don't see why  you cannot keep the string in a singleton and store it as a static reference. You can also store it in a shared preference like Doomsknight suggests, but this will not be cached in memory. Shared preferences are stored as XML files on a persistence store (against values available on a RAM). Values are retrieved back from them.

Perhaps you need a combination of the two. Store the value in a shared preference and then cache it in memory when your app starts. I'm unaware if the PreferenceManager by itself has a caching mechanism of some sort in memory.

Comment: the whole purpose of this is secure handling of the API key. I want to fetch it from my server whenever needed and keep it as a String in memory for later uses. won't simply dynamically storing this String in a Singelton be garbage collected ?